# MySQL function - how to apply multiple conditions to the select query

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL function that retrieves the stock for each customer. The function was working great, but recently I had the need to add a third parameter to my function.

**My current working function**:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getStock (productId INT, customerId INT) RETURNS INT(11)
BEGIN 
    DECLARE qty INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
    
    IF (customerId = 0)
        THEN
            SELECT (......) INTO qty 
            WHERE product_id = productId;
        ELSE
            SELECT (...) INTO QTY 
            WHERE product_id = productId AND customer_id = customerId;
    ENDIF;
    
    RETURN qty;
END;
```

The problem is that now I need to refactor this query and use three parameters. I'd like to apply a better condition, like such:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getStock (productId INT, forceCustomerId INT, ignoreCustomerId INT) RETURNS INT(11)
BEGIN                 
    DECLARE qty INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE query VARCHAR(255);

    // Something like this
    SET query = SELECT (...) INTO qty
        WHERE product_id = productId;

    IF (forceCustomerId IS NOT NULL and forceCustomerId != 0)
        SET query &= AND customer_id = forceCustomerId;

    IF (ignoreCustomerId IS NOT NULL and ignoreCustomerId != 0)
        SET query &= AND customer_id != ignoreCustomerId;
        
    RETURN qty;
END;
```

How can I achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to use PREPARE and EXECUTE to make a query with variable number of terms in the WHERE clause, but...

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/en/stored-program-restrictions.html

> SQL prepared statements (PREPARE, EXECUTE, DEALLOCATE PREPARE) can be used in stored procedures, but not stored functions or triggers. Thus, stored functions and triggers cannot use dynamic SQL (where you construct statements as strings and then execute them).

So you have to do it with one fixed query. Something like this (though I have not tested it):

```
CREATE FUNCTION getStock (productId INT, forceCustomerId INT,
    ignoreCustomerId INT) RETURNS INT(11)
BEGIN                 
    SELECT (...) INTO qty
    FROM ...
    WHERE product_id = productId
     AND (forceCustomerId IS NULL OR customer_id = forceCustomerId)
     AND (ignoreCustomerId IS NULL OR customerId != ignoreCustomerId);
        
    RETURN qty;
END;
```

Comment: I'm assuming customer_id is an auto-increment integer that starts at 1, so if the other parameters are 0 the logic still works.

Comment: That worked, but I had to change from `forceCustomerId IS NULL` to `forceCustomerId = 0`, and same for `ignoreCustomerId`.